# Opening a handle to a driver from user mode

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, vb6, wdk

I have a driver and I created a symbolic name to it. The symbolic name is ...

```
L"\\DosDevices\\hook"
```

When I try to access the device object using `CreateFile()` from `usermode`, I always get an error, `"The system cannot find the file specified".`

I tried using `CreateFile()` with the following paths ...

```
"\\.\hook"
"\\Device\\hook"
"\\\\.\\hook"
"\\.\hook"
```

but it still doesn't work.
However if i try the same API call in Visual Basic 6, "\\.\\hook" works correctly, however the documentation says that it should be "\\\\.\\hook".
What is the problem here ? What is the purpose of all these "\" and how do i make it work with Visual C++ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First comes what Chris was pointing out

```
"\\.\hook"       -> "\\\\.\\hook"
```

Thus the third variant you gave should have worked. `"\\Device\\hook"` will most definitely not work with a Win32 API. Those are limited to what's beneath `\\DosDevices` or `\\??` and its variation (per-session namespaces). `\\DosDevices` and `\\??` are usually the same location with one being a symbolic link to the other depending on the exact OS version.

There are several possible reasons why it fails. One being the namespaces and that you got those wrong. Internally the path `\\.\` (I left out the syntactic escaping of backslashes here) translates to `\??\`, which is done at the boundary between Win32 and native API. The latter path (`\??\...`) is what the native API and the OS itself understand. Any other reason would require that you post the actual code you are trying to run (the `CreateFile` call in particular). Thus, more information would be required. One question would be whether you accidentally pass a wide string to an ANSI function and thus end up looking for a path that does not exist. And there are a multitude of other possibilities all of which would be easy to rule out when you post your code.

`\\DosDevices\...` as well is the native path to the object. Don't use it from the Win32 API. See `DefineDosDevice`/`QueryDosDevice` for a glimpse on the mechanisms underneath.

For experimentation I recommend [WinObj](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657) from Sysinternals and to read up the "Windows Internals" series of books or any book on Windows drivers should have a breakdown of the topics.

Comment: Actually, the problem was i was passing a simple string to an Unicode function. The string which finally worked in Visual C++ was "L"\\\\.\\hook" mainly because the name of the device has to be of type LPCTSTR and in the headers i found it like the following :-   #ifdef UNICODE
 typedef LPCWSTR LPCTSTR; 
#else
 typedef LPCSTR LPCTSTR;
#endif

Comment: @user250687: ah cool. I did have that one in the list of possibilities ("One question would be whether you accidentally pass a wide string to an ANSI function and thus end up looking for a path that does not exist"). It's a classic. Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++, when the `\` character is encountered in a string literal, it introduces an escape sequence.

```
`\r`   - embed a CR
`\n`   - embeds a LF
`\040` - embeds an character using an octal code
```

`\\` is thus necessary to represent a single `\` character in the actual string.

So, the VB string literal `"\\.\\hook"`, would translate to the C string literal: `L"\\\\.\\\\hook"`.